# Creación de variables en un dataframe mediante una función

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo el siguiente dataframe creado por Python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado la siguiente función

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def addvariables(valor:float,opcion:int)-> str:
  retorna= ""
  if opcion == 1:   
    if valor > np.median(valor) + 1 * np.std(valor):
      retorna = "Alto" 
    else: retorna = ""
  elif opcion == 2:
    retorna = "Medio"
    if valor < np.median(valor) - 1 * np.std(valor) & np.median(valor) + 1 * np.std(valor):
      retorna = "Medio"
    else: retorna = ""
  elif opcion == 3:
    retorna = "Bajo"
    if valor < np.median(valor) - 1 * np.std(valor):
      retorna = "Bajo"
    else: retorna = ""

  return (retorna)
```

Quiero crear una nueva variable (columna) dentro del dataframe por lo cual ejecuto la función de la siguiente manera:

```
campo = "Aceleracion"
autos["vc1"] = addvariables(valor = autos[campo],opción = 1)
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en el mundo de Python y no se si esa es la manera de llamar a la función, que estoy haciendo mal?